# What does numbers in make[1] make[2] make[3] mean?

Tags: makefile

For example I get an error like this when running **makefile**:

```
make[3]: *** [/home/ziga/Downloads/openwrt/rakun_openwrt/staging_dir/host/stamp/.upx_installed] Error 1
make[2]: *** [tools/upx/install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/home/ziga/Downloads/openwrt/rakun_openwrt/staging_dir/target-powerpc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.tools_install_nynnn] Error 2
```

What does the number in the square brackets in **make[3]**, **make[2]** and **make[1]**. I am not trying to solve this curent error. I am just curious about the syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basicly it shows the deepth of [recursion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion)

Comment: Thank you very much. It will really help to debug.